# Prove that $16\cos^5A-20\cos^3A+5\cos A=\cos5A$

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove that 
>   $$16\cos^5A-20\cos^3A+5\cos A=\cos5A$$

My solution begins here;
$$
\begin{align}
\text{RHS} & =\cos5A \\
& =\cos(A+4A) \\
& =\cos A\cos4A-\sin A\sin4A \\
& =\cos A(2\cos^2 2A-1)-\sin A(2\sin2A\cos2A) \\
& =2\cos A\cos^2 2A-\cos A-2\sin A\sin2A\cos2A \\
& =2\cos A\cos^2 2A-\cos A-2\sin A(2\sin A\cos A)\cos2A
\end{align}
$$
Now how do I move on?

Comment: Your question has been answered very adequately below, but you should try using De Moivre's Theorem - it's a lot easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use
$$
2\cos x=e^{ix}+e^{-ix}
$$
Then
$$
32\cos^5x=e^{5ix}+5e^{3ix}+10e^{ix}+10e^{-ix}+5e^{-3ix}+e^{-5ix}=
2\cos5x+10\cos3x+20\cos x
$$
Moreover
$$
8\cos^3x=e^{3ix}+3e^{ix}+3e^{-ix}+e^{-3ix}=
2\cos3x+6\cos x
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
16\cos^5x-20\cos^3x+5\cos x
&=(\cos5x+5\cos3x+10\cos x)-5(\cos3x+3\cos x)+5\cos x\\
&=\cos5x
\end{align}

This is actually backwards, so here's a different proof:
\begin{align}
\cos 5x+i\sin 5x
&=(\cos x+i\sin x)^5\\
&=\cos^5x+5i\cos^4x\sin x-10\cos^3x\sin^2x\\
&\qquad-10i\cos^2x\sin^3x+5\cos x\sin^4x
+i\sin^5x
\end{align}
Taking the real part
$$
\cos5x=\cos^5x-10\cos^3x(1-\cos^2x)+5\cos x(1-\cos^2x)^2
$$
and you can finish.

Answer (score 3):

Now use double angle formulae to write $\cos 2A$ in terms of $\cos A$, then turn any $\sin^2 A$ into $1-\cos^2 A$

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to replace each instance of $\sin^2 A$ with $1-\cos^2A$ before doing the last simplifications.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the Chebyschev polynomial of the first kind by the recurrence

$$T_0(A)=1\\T_1(A)=A\\T_{n+1}(A)=2AT_n(A)-T_{n-1}(A)$$ you have the known result $$T_n(A)=\cos nA$$ You can verify at once for $n=5$ your formule.

**Comment for laamuser user**: Chebyschev polynomial of the first kind is some "magic" to find $\cos nx$. For $n=5$ you have successively
$$T_2(A)=2A\cdot A-1=2A^2-1$$  $$T_3(A)=2A(2A^2-1)-A=4A^3-3A$$  $$T_4(A)=2A(4A^3-3A)-(2A^2-1)=8A^4-8A^2+1$$ $$T_5(A)=2A(8A^4-8A^2+1)-(4A^3-3A)$$
i.e.
$$T_5(A)=16A^5-20A^3+5A$$ and you have $$T_5(\cos x)=\cos 5x$$

Comment: How does this help the OP with "Now how do I move on?"

Comment: @ piquito, I could not understand it. Could you please put it simply..

Comment: @laamuser user: read the edit please.

Comment: @SimpleArt: I wanted to give additional information concerning $\cos nx$ in function of $\cos x$ to laamuser user. (I'm a writer and I love too much art like you).

Comment: @Piquito Sadly, I've found making an answer like this can get negative attention or positive attention, so be careful.  (I like the art of math.)

Comment: With just @laamuser user gives positive attention it is enough for me (I hope he have enjoyed that $T_2$, $T_3$ and $T_4$ give $\cos 2A$, $\cos 3A$ and $\cos 4A$, respectively and be convinced he can find this way $\cos nA$ in function of $\cos A$)